# Nested Loop: Counting letters in a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following question for one of my classes but I am a bit stuck. I have created the below code but when I print it only prints the count of the last word only not for each word.

"Use a nested loop to count the letters of each element in the `nmrls` list, then print the element along with its number of letters."

```
!pip install inflect
import inflect


nmrls = inflect.engine()
x=[]
for i in range (0,22):
    x.append(nmrls.number_to_words(i))   
for nmrls in x:
    count=0
    for letter in x:
        count+=1
    print(nmrls, count)
```

Comment: what is the content of `x` after you add the words ?

Comment: You're looping over `x` twice, so the `count` you're getting is actually the number of items inside of `x`, not the number of letters in `nmrls`.

Comment: `for letter in x:`  =>  `for letter in nmrls:`

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue :) Looping over x twice was overriding the value.

```
!pip install inflect
import inflect


nmrls = inflect.engine()
x=[]
for i in range (0,22):
    x.append(nmrls.number_to_words(i))   
for nmrls in x:
    count=0
    for letter in nmrls:
        count+=1
    print(nmrls, count)
```